# Proper use of ‘case-in-point’ at the start of a statement

Tags: phrase-usage

I’m writing an essay on globalisation and writing a point on how service jobs are harder to outsource, as compared to manufacturing jobs. At the end of my argument, is it grammatically correct to write

Case in point: You can’t serve your customer in XYZ mall from China.

(I substitute XYZ mall with the name of an actual mall in the area of context)

Is this usage correct? I’m trying to use case in point in a mildly sarcastic or humorous way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this sense, "case in point" is synonymous with "for example".

Comment: When talking, people use it without an "a" or "one", very often...

Answer (score 0):

a case in point  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/case+in+point)

> An example that demonstrates a point being made as truthful or correct

As in:

> It's important to always encrypt your data so hackers can't steal it.
>   The recent data breach is a case in point.

Your usage is OK:  "Case in point: You can’t serve your customer in XYZ mall from China."  Consider: *As a case in point ...*

Comment: "**You**" shouldn't be capitalised, it is part of the same sentence, following a colon.

Comment: @Nigel Touch If you check in various style guides etc (_or_ in the related question on ELU), you'll see that capitalisation after a colon is rather old-fashioned but not incorrect.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/case_in_point) offers: "A few cases in point: Two men attacked a British executive on the subway." Although more context would be useful there.